# ValueError: Unable to parse string ""60800""

Tags: python, pandas, string

So i want to convert a column of strings in floats with pandas using :

```
out['Day ahead'] = pd.to_numeric(out['Day ahead'],downcast = 'float')
```

[Screenshot of my excel :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2dnM.png)

I have no clue why the consol returns `ValueError: Unable to parse string ""60800""`

Thank you very much !

Comment: Hi there, could you copy and paste in some of the Excel sheet values, under their column names, so that people don't have to open a link? There is a code block format option for the questions and answers.

Comment: You will have to strip the additional quotation marks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems like the quotes are part of the string. If so, you have to first replace them before you convert to float. Kindly follow [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) while asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
out['Day ahead'] = out['Day ahead'].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1]).astype(float)
```

Basically, `x[1:-1]` will strip the double quote because it takes the second character until the second last. I suggest this method because it looks like all the values in your column are double quoted

EDIT: thanks to @Manakin

Another two methods seem to be even simpler.

1. using `str.strip()`

```
out['Day ahead'] = out['Day ahead'].str.strip('"').astype(float)
```

2. using 'str.replace()`

```
out['Day ahead'] = out['Day ahead'].str.replace('"', '').astype(float)
```

Comment: no need for the lambda here look at `str.strip()` or `str.replace`

Comment: Thank you very much Christopher it worked ! The wierd thing is that i checked it wasn't a double quote issue by coping pasting one of the cells in python like this : type("60800") and it returned 'str'.

Comment: @RaphaelMaillard, not sure why you said it's not double quote because what you pasted in your comment is indeed double quote. But anyway, I'm happy that my answer helped.

Comment: yeah i guessed it's confusing but I think that the second quote comes from the python's consol that quoted the error. Since the number was already quoted in the excel ...  if you look at the excel's screenshot you'll see that there is only one quote. Have a great day sir !

Comment: @RaphaelMaillard, LOL. I refer this -> `"` <- is a double quote, and this -> `'` <- is a single quote :)

Comment: @RaphaelMaillard, would you mind to accept my answer if it is helpful?