# ValueError: Unable to parse string " " at position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

I am running into a surprising error with no trace. I tried to convert a column full of float values into float type but throwed me error at a particular index. But, value at that index shows float value. I have no idea how to overcome this problem?
My code:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['col_A'])

>> ValueError: Unable to parse string " " at position 4473

type(df['col_A'].loc[4473])
>> float
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Unable to parse string ""60800""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913502/valueerror-unable-to-parse-string-60800)

Comment: Note that `loc[4473]` is the row with that index, which does not necessarily match the 0-based line number.  Check `iloc[4473]`.

Comment: @TimRoberts You were correct. It gave me `' '`. So I found the bug. The question is how do I drop it? do you think `df = df.drop([4473])` will work?

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_numeric(df['col_A'], errors='coerce')`?. This will transform ' ' to `np.nan`